# Webpack: Set the path for my assets according to the entry name

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

Using webpack, I have a multiple page application which works with multiple entries. I have a project tree like this:

```
-- webpack.config.js
-- src/
    -- first/
        -- main.ts
        -- helper.ts
        -- main.css
        -- index.html
    -- second/
        -- main.ts
        -- main.css
        -- index.html
    -- assets/
        -- myAsset1.png
        -- myAsset2.png
        -- myAsset3.png
```

I wanted something tidy and organised by folder. To do so, I add `[name]/...` each time for the `name` or the `filename` like this:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    first: './src/first/main.ts',
    second: './src/second/main.ts',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // output directory
    filename: '[name]/script.js', // name of the generated bundle
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // TypeScript
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
        },
      },
      // Style
      {
        test: /\.s?[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      // Fonts & Images
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|jpg|png|svg|md)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              name: '[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src')],
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/first/index.html'),
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['first'],
      filename: 'first/index.html',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/second/index.html',
      inject: true,
      chunks: ['second'],
      filename: 'second/index.html',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name]/style.css',
      chunkFilename: '[name]/style.css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

**The result will be:**

```
-- dist/
    -- first/
        -- script.js
        -- style.css
        -- index.html
    -- second/
        -- script.js
        -- style.css
        -- index.html
    -- myAsset1.png
    -- myAsset2.png
    -- myAsset3.png
```

However, I would like the assets in the folder name according to the entry from where it is imported. Indeed, `myAssets1.png` and `myAssets2.png` are imported from `main.ts` of `first` folder and `myAssets3.png` is imported from `main.ts` of `second` folder

```
-- dist/
    -- first/
        -- script.js
        -- style.css
        -- index.html
        -- myAsset1.png
        -- myAsset2.png
    -- second/
        -- script.js
        -- style.css
        -- index.html
        -- myAsset3.png
```

How could I set the path for my assets according to the entry name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to specify that the assets that [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#function-1) is handling will be saved in your required place few things should happend:

1. you need to determine which entry point is the issuer of this file
2. inject it as a `resourceQuery`
3. use the injected `resourceQuery` in the `name` function of the `file-loader` to specify the path.

In order to achieve 1,2 you can create a custom loader, which will extract the issuer & attach the query.

```js
// entry-dir-injector-loader.js
const path = require('path');

function recursiveIssuer(m) {
  if (m.issuer && m.issuer.context) {
    return recursiveIssuer(m.issuer);
  } else if (m.context) {
    return m.context;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = function (content) {
  const entry = recursiveIssuer(this._module);
  const entryRelativePath = path.relative(this.rootContext, entry).replace('src/', '');
  this.resourceQuery = `?entryDir=${entryRelativePath}`;
  return content;
};
```

Then specify the `name` as a **function**, extract the query.

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|jpg|png|svg|md)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              name(resourcePath, resourceQuery) {
                const entryDir = resourceQuery
                  .substring(1)
                  .split('&')
                  .filter((key) => key.startsWith('entryDir='))
                  .map((key) => key.split('=').pop())
                  .join('');

                return path.join(entryDir, `[name].[ext]`);
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: './entry-dir-injector-loader.js',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: In fact, I missed one part in my explanation. All the assets are in the same folder of the src. So I can not check like that. This is why I would like to check from the entry name. I updated my question. It is more clear with the project tree. @felixmosh

Comment: Check the 3rd argument, it should contain the file that required your asset.

Comment: The 3rd argument gives me the path of the project `C:\Users\PierBJX\Documents\TestProject`

Comment: Will you accept solution with query? so you need to specify in the import of the asset.
`import image from './path/to/image.png?dir=second'

Comment: Actually, with what I am doing I can not really do that

Comment: Can you share a github repo with your test project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214656/discussion-between-felixmosh-and-pierbjx).

Comment: In fact with this solution, we assume that the string after 'src/' is the same as the entry point. But what if the entry point is different?

Comment: But the string that I can manipulate is the path of the entry './src/first/main.ts' and if the entry name is 'welcome'. I will have a folder first with assets and a folder welcome with the script.js, style.css and index.html.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue, you wrote that the custom loader assumes that your code is inside `src/`, if it doesn't suits your need change it